# What to start with when building an IDE?

Tags: compiler-construction, ide, compiler-theory

I thoroughly read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465873/concepts-required-in-building-an-ide-compiler) question, and then the idea of building an IDE struck me.

I am a fresh graduate, and would like to know the conceptual as well as actual steps to be taken when building an IDE.

I have had no homework before posting this question, but I am sure I will be able o get an efficient answer here.

Comment: could u please elaborate ur question.....

Comment: Start with studying the existing IDEs: Emacs, vim (both within the Unix ecosystem), Eclipse, MonoDevelop, etc. All are different, and if you're going to start from scratch, you'd need to know the drawbacks of the others.

Comment: Search for light table, a radical attempt on IDE development.

Comment: @SK-logic I guess Emacs and vim are editors not IDEs. Eclipse, QtCreator, Visual Studio are examples of IDEs.

Comment: This question is entirely too broad in scope to be answered here. Questions should be specific and concise. The [faq] says "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face", and "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.". Voting to close as "not a real question". "Explain the concept of writing an IDE as well as the actual steps" isn't specific. Voting to close as "not a real question" because it's entirely too vague and broad in scope to be answered here. Good luck.

Comment: @AdityaKumar, emacs is much more then just IDE - it's a complete OS. Vim is quite close to a classic definition of IDE.

Answer (score 1):

To get started you should look at existing IDEs and their features. To get a bare minimum working IDE, it should have:

1. A text editor (to write code) with some syntax highlighting hopefully
2. A build system (to facilitate compilation of multiple source files and link them together to generate executable/library)

You might want to get an open-source text editor (http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-free-or-open-source-text-editors-for-developers/1031) and integrate an existing build system (e.g. CMake, Makefile etc.) to come up with a working version of your IDE.

You may also like to provide a console window so that programmer can execute commands etc.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the above people said, real-time syntax highlighting would be another basic feature. Based on what type of file is being viewed in the IDE, have different sets of syntax highlighting (e.g. XML file syntax highlighting would be different from .cs file syntax highlighting, etc.).