# How does IDE knows unused import and functions

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide, unused-variables

What is the mechanism of IDE like IntelliJ, Android Studio and Eclipse, etc. detects unused imports, variables and functions?

Also, We don't have to manually "save" in IntelliJ, what happens every time I edit something in this kind of IDE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IDEs use complex algorithms for grammars, lexical analyzing and parsing of the sources. See more info here: 
[Concepts required in building an IDE/compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465873/concepts-required-in-building-an-ide-compiler)

About the saving: instead of waiting the user to press "Save", Intellij IDEA waits for an event to happen, like editor losing focus, closing the edited file, etc. Then it saves.